# Mockito doThrow() not throwing exception

Tags: java, mockito

There's been similar questions, but none of those can solve my current problem

Say I have a fairly simple class:

```
public class ClassA {
    private final Object someVariable;
    
    public classA(Object obj) {
        this.someVariable = obj
    }

    public void Object someMethod(Object obj) throws SomeException {
    //does stuff
    }
}
```

Now, I create an instance of this class in a diff class

```
public class ClassB {
    private final Object anotherVariable;

    public void Object anotherMethod() throws SomeException {
        try {
            ClassA objectA = new ClassA(anotherVariable)
            objectA.someMethod()
        } catch {
            // does stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The end goal is to test the catch block by throwing an exceptions as so

```
@Mock
ClassA myObject = new ClassA(obj)

...

@Test(expected = SomeException.class)
public void myTest()throws Exception {
    doThrow(new SomeException()).when(myObject).someMethod(any());
}
```

For some reason the exceptions is just never thrown. I've also tried replacing the `any()` with both valid and invalid objects, and it still doesn't work.

Edit1:

Whilst fishing for a solution, this for some reason passes the test:

```
@Test(expected = SomeException.class)
public voif Test() throws Exception {     
    doThrow(new someException()).when(myObject).someMethod(any());
    when(myObject.someMethod(any())).thenThrow(new someException());
}
```

Any explanation as to why this works? Is this bad practice or something?

Comment: Try this `doThrow(SomeException.class)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason is that you never call the method:

```
@Test(expected = SomeException.class)
public void myTest(0 throws Exception {
    // here you stub the method
    doThrow(new SomeException()).when(myObject).someMethod(any());
    // also it should probably be like this:
    // doThrow(new SomeException()).when(myObject).someMethod();
    // because the method in ClassA does not have any params

    // you need it to be called somewhere
    // you can do that explicitly
    myObject.someMethod(/*perhaps some param here*/);

    // or you can call some other method which calls this one
    // on the mock - then you should get an exception as well
}
```

Also, there is a little issue in ClassB:

```
public void Object anotherMethod() throws SomeException {
    try {
        // you instantiate obj of type ClassA here
        // which means you cannot mock it if you need
        // to test anotherMethod()
        ClassA objectA = new ClassA(anotherVariable)
        objectA.someMethod()
    } catch {
            // does stuff
    }
}
```

If you'd like to test `ClassB.anotherMethod()` you need to get rid of this super tight coupling:

```
ClassA objectA = new ClassA(anotherVariable)
```

Consider approach like this:

```
public class ClassB {
    private final ClassA objectA;

    public ClassB(ClassA obj) {
        // now you can provide any instance of ClassA instead
        // of having it created in try-block later
        // so when you need ClassB in real code, you can create
        // some real instance of ClassA and pass to this conctructor
        // and for test you can pass mock 
        this.objectA = obj;
    }

    public void Object anotherMethod() throws SomeException {
        try {
            objectA.someMethod()
        } catch {
            // does stuff
        }
    }
}
```

What this gives us:

```
@Mock
ClassA myObject = new ClassA(obj)

...

@Test(expected = SomeException.class)
public void myTest()throws Exception {
    // stub someMethod on object of ClassA
    doThrow(new SomeException()).when(myObject).someMethod();

    ClassB objB = new ClassB(myObject);
    
    // now you can test it, and inside anotherMethod()
    // there will be a call to someMethod() on a mock
    // so you will get an exception
    objB.anotherMethod();
}
```

Comment: This worked! My next issue/questions is, the end goal is to basically test the catch block in ClassB where someMethod is called, by using doThrow() I've tried to call anotherMethod which in turn calls someMethod but no success

Comment: @ElizabethSallow I updated my answer with more details about how you can test your ClassB. Hope they make some sense :)

Comment: Oh this makes more sense now, thanks! Upvoted and accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume since u are mocking Class A below line

```
@Mock
ClassA myObject = new ClassA(obj) //u r creating new instance
```

do

```
@Mock
ClassA myObject; //assuming u r using initMock or @InjectMocks
```

or

```
ClassA myObject = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
```

then Mock the behavior how u mock a method call

```
when(myObject.someMethod(any()))
      .thenThrow(new SomeException());
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, though may I ask the difference between that and     doThrow(new `SomeException()).when(myObject).someMethod(any())`;

Comment: one is for mock another is for stub object